# Titanium share Intent with page link

Tags: android, android-intent, titanium, titanium-mobile

I'm developing a Mobile application and I need to make an intent.

The goal is to share a link with an image.
Like this example:

[image]

There is a way to make it?

Because with the only type "text/plain" I don't know how to put an image!

I'm developing the app with Titanium (Javascript) but a Java (Android) example is welcome too!

Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

did you try this ? http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/149385/sharing-image-via-androidintent

```
var file = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(Ti.Filesystem.externalStorageDirectory,'viaInstaCheckIn.jpeg');
var B = file.read();

var shareIntent = Ti.Android.createIntent({
    action: Ti.Android.ACTION_SEND,
    type: "image/jpeg"
});

shareIntent.putExtra(Ti.Android.EXTRA_TITLE, "Photo via fb.com/InstaCheckInHD");
shareIntent.putExtra(Ti.Android.EXTRA_TEXT, "Photo By @InstaCheckInHD");
shareIntent.putExtraUri(Ti.Android.EXTRA_STREAM, B.nativePath);
Ti.Android.currentActivity.startActivity(Ti.Android.createIntentChooser(shareIntent, "Share image"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused as to what you are trying to do. What's sharing the link, and with what? external links that will open your app? your app needs to start another app? Please elaborate...